# How should we represent a Stack Exchange moderator position on our Stack Overflow Jobs profile?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

For the purposes of this question, we will assume that it's a good idea to put your Stack Exchange site moderator position on your Developer Story or CV.

---

The only options that make sense would be Position or Other.

If I select Position, I need to put a company name. It seems incorrect to put Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow or the name of the site there. Some of the other fields make some sense - you can use the company website to link to the SE site or your profile there, and it gives you the chance to denote if it's current or past. However, fields like technologies don't really make sense and can hurt profile completion for not having jobs with technologies marked.

If I select Other, I'm not sure how to fill it out. Although it doesn't apply to me, there doesn't appear to be an end date, which can be deceptive to readers. The description field would have to be overloaded (but it does support Markdown) to link to the site. It's also easier to complete this particular form with the information.

I suspect that this would be the same as any other volunteer position that you would put on your resume or CV, so I would lean toward using Position. However, the Position form is definitely geared toward development or other technical position, which may or may not be useful to list non-development or non-technical positions (like several volunteer positions).

Does SE have any guidance for this?

Comment: I wonder if the Developer Story is geared towards volunteer work at all.  We both seem to have the same notion(s) as to where to include it, but I'm not so certain that this was built with that in mind.

Comment: @Makoto I'd agree with that. Putting volunteer work on it seems awkward.

Comment: Maybe they could just have a section that shows what sites you are a moderator on that can be opted in and select which ones show.

Comment: I think an actual Volunteer option is a good addition. I assumed it just wasn't in version 1 but would come later. Being able to show off that you get out and help your community, even in unrelated instances of working for Habitat for Humanity or other such organizations, is a great show of character and willingness to help. It's relevant to pretty much every job. I have immense respect for companies that give employees a few free days a year to just go out and volunteer for something, and it'd be nice to show off that you do that.

Comment: Some people make major contributions to open source projects over many years in addition to their paying jobs. It seems to me that such work is similar to volunteering and also to being a moderator -- they all take time and effort and may be desirable to add to a CV or to the developer story. Having a way to clearly, but optionally, show such activities would be nice.

Comment: @AdrianHHH The thing is, Open Source contributions are already covered. You can use either Open Source to denote a project (likely one you start or are an active contributor to) or Feature to denote a contribution of a bug fix or patch or a one-time thing. Volunteering doesn't seem to be well-covered. Position is probably the best, but it is really different than a paid job and should probably be represented differently, especially if you volunteer for an organization that also has full-time employees.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thank you for that clarification. I did not know that the developer story explicitly covers Open Source work. My earlier comment was intended to support your question.

Comment: If SO thinks "volunteering" is too open-ended (and don't want Habitat and such listed for some reason), they could instead use a label like "professional service", which is how academics refer to their volunteer work refereeing journal submissions, organizing conferences, etc.

Comment: We do have some guidance coming soon. Right now, this would fit in the Other category but it's missing a few things that like end date as you pointed out.  We're looking at a few ways to fix this category and should have an update soon.

Comment: @bluefeet Would this guidance for Other include all volunteering positions? I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Yes, that's what we're looking at.  You should be able to include Volunteer as the Category in other, but after discussing it we realized we're missing some things like the end date. Other is supposed to be the flexible option that you can use to customize your Dev Story.

Comment: @bluefeet Awesome. Can't wait to hear more.

Comment: @bluefeet Is there any update to this? The "Other" option is now gone and there's still no way to represent volunteering (either as a separate action or a toggle on Position).

Comment: @ThomasOwens They are still adjusting categories, you should be able to use the new Milestone option for volunteering.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks for the update, but the Milestone option has the same problem as the Other used to - no end date.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'll pass it along to the team